# How to convert a string "-2" into float in python?

Tags: python

```
>>> a=("-2","-2")
>>> float(a[0][0])
```

This gives me an error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): -
```

So how do I convert it ?

Comment: To debug your problem yourself the first thing to try would be `>>> print(a[0][0])`. That should give you a pretty good clue as to what happened.

Answer (score 7):

Use `a[0]` instead (`a[0][0]` is the first character of the first element, not the first element).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but your code has an error:

```
float(a[0])
```

will do. 
If you need 2.2 as result, then

```
x = 0.0; # python 2.x
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    x += a[i] * 10**-i
```

Comment: Its a 2 dimensional array . Thus in a data-set of negative numbers stored as strings, how do I convert them into float

Comment: Em.. which code block returns an error? I'm 100% sure that `x = float(('2','2')[0])` works.

Comment: You see, a = ('-2', '-2') is treated as 1-dimensional array (actually a tuple) in Python. To get another dimension you must add it explicitly: ` a = ( ('-2', '-2'), ) # note the last comma`. Now you can do `float(a[0][0])`.

Comment: See my data set has strings which are defined like this ("-2","-2") . Thus here the negative sign when converted to float gives an error . As in when I do float.(a[0][0]) (That is the first element of the 2-dimensional array it gives an error

Comment: Here, what happens when you do `('-2',-'2)[0][0]` : with first index, you get the 0th element of the tuple -> `'-2'`. Then you get the 0th character of the string -> '-'. Because '-' is not a real number, it can't be converted into float.

Comment: @mekasperasky: Your comments make no sense.  Please **update** the question with your **real** data and the **real** code which **really** reads that data.

Answer (score 1):

It is one dimensional array, not multi dimensional array. So you have specify it as follows:

```
float(a[0])
float(a[1])
```

It can be specified that a[0] is the first place number '-2' and a[1] is the second place number '-2'. Try it.. I hope it should be helpful for  you.

Answer (score 0):

You're indexing incorrectly, if you want a tuple that contains floats for these two strings, then you have to do the following:

```
(float(a[0]), float(a[1]))
```

Note that the outer brackets are defining a new tuple.

Comment: Or use ``map(float, a)`` to convert all elements of an arbitrary size input.